# Write text over image using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to generate PDF. 
I am using FPDF to generate pdf file. 
I generate the pdf with the content text and image. 
Now i want to make the image as background image. 
So the scenario is text would be over image. I tried many solution but any solution is working for me. I generated the PDF using below code.

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$title = 'Without User Details';
$img_title = 'Your Voucher Image is-:  ';
$php2pdf = '';
$php2pdf .= 'Your Voucher Code is-:  ';
$php2pdf .= $voucher_prefix;
$php2pdf .= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'voucher_start_digit', true);

 if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):
 $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
 $image_url = $image[0];
 endif;

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->SetTitle($title);
$pdf->MultiCell($w, $h, $title);
$pdf->Ln(3);
$pdf->Cell(90,90,$php2pdf);
$pdf->Ln(20);
$pdf->MultiCell(40, 10, $img_title);
$pdf->Image($image_url,30,60,90,0); ob_start();
$pdf->Output();
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: so you want to make the image as the background image?

Comment: http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/fpdf-background-image-510220.html

Comment: I already tried this solution , but not worked for me. It is not making image as background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer !!! It is by using Transparency of FPDF. 
For that we have to use its extended Alphapdf class.

Reference : 
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script74.php

Answer (score 3):

Try this way it's working

```
[![require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');  
$pdf = new FPDF(); 


$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('PC_Letterhead.jpg',0,0,210,0); ob_start();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',22);
 $pdf->Cell(0,20,'Your Shipping',0,1); 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12); 

          $pdf->SetFillColor(224,224,224); //Set background of the cell to be that grey color
           $pdf->Cell(40,12,"Label",1,0,'C',true);
          $pdf->Cell(40,12,"Quanitity",1,1,'C',true); //the 1 before the 'C' instead of 0 in previous lines tells it to move down by the height of the cell after writing this
           $pdf->Cell(40,12,"SIZE",1,0,'C');
          $pdf->Cell(40,12,"1",1,1,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(40,12,"COLOR",1,0,'C');
          $pdf->Cell(40,12,"2",1,1,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(40,12,"NECK",1,0,'C');
          $pdf->Cell(40,12,"3",1,1,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(40,12,"HANDLE",1,0,'C');
          $pdf->Cell(40,12,"4",1,1,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(40,12,"VENTS",1,0,'C');
          $pdf->Cell(40,12,"5",1,1,'C');
$pdf->Output();
ob_end_flush();][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution to this. If you're having an image in FPDF overlay the text you called before it, this is a simple solution that just worked for me:

1. Move the `Cell()` call for the text before the image to a line BELOW the `Image()` call.
2. Then change the Y position of the `Cell()` call to a **NEGATIVE** number, which will move the line position up on top of the image before printing the text

Example (in inches):

```
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',42);
$pdf->Cell(0,0, $certificate->displayname ,0,1,'C');

$pdf->Image('../images/cert-body-subject.png' ,0,4.2,11,0);
```

becomes instead

```
$pdf->Image('../images/cert-body-subject.png' ,0,4.2,11,0);

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',42);
$pdf->Cell(0,-.1, $certificate->displayname ,0,1,'C');
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if anyone is still looking for this but in my case i used a custom function that was made by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1685196/michel and posted on [Is it possible to cut text on cell in in FPDF library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48945844/is-it-possible-to-cut-text-on-cell-in-in-fpdf-library), when used overlaps the cells below the "BreakCell" so you will need to set x and y but it makes possible to write text over an image without using transparency.

```
function BreakCell($w, $h, $txt, $border=0, $align='J', $fill=false){
    if(!isset($this->CurrentFont))
        $this->Error('No font has been set');
    $cw = &$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    if($w==0)
        $w = $this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax = ($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
    $s = str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    $nb = strlen($s);
    if($nb>0 && $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
        $nb--;
    $b = 0;
    if($border)$b=$border;
    $sep = -1;
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $l = 0;
    $ns = 0;
    $nl = 1;
    $stop=false;
    while($i<$nb && $stop===false)
    {
        $c = $s[$i];
        if($c=="\n")
        {
            if($this->ws>0)
            {
                $this->ws = 0;
                $this->_out('0 Tw');
            }
            $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$i-$j), 0, 0,'C');
            $stop=true;
            break;
        }
        $l += $cw[$c];
        if($l>$wmax)
        {
            if($sep==-1)
            {
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
                if($this->ws>0)
                {
                    $this->ws = 0;
                    $this->_out('0 Tw');
                }
            $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$i-$j-3).'...',0,0,'C');
            $stop=true;
            break;
            }
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
    if($stop===false){
        if($this->ws>0)
        {
            $this->ws = 0;
            $this->_out('0 Tw');
        }
        $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$i-$j),$b,0,$align,$fill);
    }
    $this->x = $this->lMargin;
}
```